Unable to Enable Time To Live (TTL) for AWS DynamoDB Table in Terraform
I'm trying to enable TTL (Time-to-Live) on an AWS DynamoDB table using Terraform. According to the documentation, the aws_dynamodb_table resource should support TTL, but when I run the terraform plan command, it doesn't detect any changes. I expect it to find the TTL syntax and show one change to apply.
However, the TTL configuration doesn't seem to be detected while running plan command. Am I missing something in the setup or usage?
Terraform Code
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "vehicle_id_table" {
  name         = var.dynamodb_vehicle_id_table_name
  hash_key     = "id"
  billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"

  point_in_time_recovery {
    enabled = true
  }

  attribute {
    name = "id"
    type = "S"
  }

  ttl {
    enabled        = true
    attribute_name = "ttl"
  }
}

What did I try?
I added the ttl block to the aws_dynamodb_table resource to enable Time-To-Live (TTL) for the ttl attribute in my DynamoDB table.
Terraform command
terraform plan -var-file="tfvars/dev.tfvars" -target=aws_dynamodb_table.vehicle_id_table

What was I expecting?
I expected Terraform to detect the change in the TTL configuration and show a plan to enable it for the DynamoDB table. Specifically, terraform plan should recognize the ttl block in the resource.

which terraform and aws providers version are you using?
I used terraform v1.5.6 and aws_provider version = ">= 4.67.0" and i applied the same configuration without the ttl, then i added the ttl object, and the plan detected it without any issue: 
try to check the configuration within the state file to see wether the ttl is configured there or no using:
terraform state show aws_dynamodb_table.vehicle_id_table

and ensure that the Terraform state reflects the TTL settings.
Also maybe the TTL is already added manually, that's why the plan is not detecting anything. But, terraform detects it without any issue.
